# Como imprimir o conteúdo dentro de uma div HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, impressão, div

Tenho uma página e nela o conteúdo que quero imprimir.

Criei um comando em JavaScript, porém esse comando faz imprimir a página inteira.

Existe alguma forma de ser impresso apenas o conteúdo de uma `div`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Não é possível selecionar uma `div` para impressão com JavaScript, até porque esta não é uma função dele. Existe uma solução que utiliza apenas CSS:

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printable, #printable * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #printable {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Desta forma, apenas o que estiver dentro deste elemento `printable` no HTML será exibido.

Comment: A última regra não pode ser problemática se o `#printable` estiver dentro de um outro elemento já posicionado? Não seria mais seguro utilizar `fixed`?

Comment: Sim, você tem razão, aqui eu assumi que o elemento não está dentro de outro com `position: relative;`. Por este motivo editei minha resposta, obrigado.

Comment: Não seria melhor substituir `#printable` por `.printable`? Pode ser que ele precise atribuir esta propriedade a mais de um elemento, em algum momento.

Comment: @CalebeOliveira, na pergunta ele solicita "apenas uma div". Mesmo assim, este método não funcionaria para mais de uma div.

Comment: Um padrão atualmente é ter uma folha de estilo para a "versão para impressão" do site e uma folha padrão. Isso casa muito bem com esta resposta.

Comment: Essa solução não funciona caso vc tenha um conteúdo que dê mais de uma folha de impressão!

Answer (score 22):

```
var conteudo = document.getElementById('sua_div').innerHTML,
    tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');

tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
tela_impressao.window.print();
tela_impressao.window.close();
```

Esse código deve ser executado somente ao acionar algum evento do mouse, caso contrário o bloqueador de popups bloqueará a ação.

Funciona muito bem. Teste!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gFtUY/

Comment: Ok, mas e se vc quiser preservar todo o CSS que foi carregado no <head>?

Comment: @Slowaways Nesse caso é melhor usar css `@media print`, conforme a resposta acima

Answer (score 6):

As soluções apresentadas acima não são tão flexíveis.
Elas apresentam pelo menos um dos problemas listados:

- Não tem suporte pra imprimir conteúdo grande que dão mais de uma folha
- Removem todo o CSS já processado

Apresento aqui minha solução usando jQuery:

Código JS:

```
function printBy(selector){
    var $print = $(selector)
        .clone()
        .addClass('print')
        .prependTo('body');

    // Stop JS execution
    window.print();

    // Remove div once printed
    $print.remove();
}
```

Estilo CSS:

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
    #printable {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #printable ~ * {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeita a solução! Obrigado por compartilhar!!

Answer (score 5):

Resumindo:

```
<script>
function cont(){
   var conteudo = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
   tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');
   tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
   tela_impressao.window.print();
   tela_impressao.window.close();
}
</script>

<div id="print" class="conteudo">
// conteúdo a ser impresso pode ser um form ou um table.
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="cont();" value="Imprimir Div separadamente">
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
  function printDiv(divID) {
        //pega o Html da DIV
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        //pega o HTML de toda tag Body
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        //Alterna o body 
        document.body.innerHTML = 
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
          divElements + "</body>";

        //Imprime o body atual
        window.print();

        //Retorna o conteudo original da página. 
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

    }
```

E também pode-se usar um pop-up.

```js
    function printDiv(divID)  
    {
        var conteudo = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;  
        var win = window.open();  
        win.document.write(conteudo);  
        win.print();  
        win.close();//Fecha após a impressão.  
    }
```

Comment: O seu primeiro método pode causar incompatibilidade caso o usuário utilize JavaScript para controlar alguns elementos ou utiliza "widgets" de terceiros. Sem contar que perderia a estilização do CSS.

Comment: Uma outra fórmula que pode vir a funcionar é inserir uma div branca por cima de toda a página e dentro dela inserir a div que deseja imprimir. Preservando o código renderizado.