# Imprimir pagina html sem perder as configurações

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir através de uma função JS, todas as informações contidas dentro de uma `<div>`. Porém teria que imprimir apenas o que contém na div, sem perder as cores e formatação.

Comment: Seria a mesma dúvida [**dessa pergunta**?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/782/4808)

Comment: exatamente, obrigada.