# Imprimir somente uma parte de uma página HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando imprimir somente a parte de uma página HTML que possui um código de barras.
HTML:

```
<div class="barcode-img">
            <svg id="barcode"
                 jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
                 jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold"
                 style="width: 30%; height: 30%;">
            </svg>

            <script>
                JsBarcode("#barcode", "<?php echo $bar_number; ?>", {
                    format: "ean13",
                    width: 3
                });
            </script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#barcode, #barcode *{
    visibility: visible;
}

#barcode
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Vi em muitos lugares soluções semelhantes a essa, mas fazendo isso o meu código de barras aparece duas vezes, ou mais, na página de impressão.

Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Eu tentei da forma que dizer lá, e obtive esse problema da imagem

Comment: Testa a resposta do Gabriel. Ele pega o conteudo de uma determinada div, escreve num doc em branco e só imprime ele. é isso que tu precisa. =)

Comment: Não funcionou também, fazendo do jeito que ele disse a imagem nem aparece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var conteudo = document.getElementById('barcode').innerHTML;
var telaImpressao = window.open('about:blank');

telaImpressao.document.write(conteudo);
telaImpressao.window.print();
telaImpressao.window.close();
```

Esta resposta está disponível [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/782/como-imprimir-o-conte%C3%BAdo-dentro-de-uma-div-html)

Você copia o conteúdo da sua div para uma página nova e a imprime.

Comment: Eu estava tentando só com a imagem, com a div inteira funcionou :)