# Imprimir query dinâmica

Tags: php, mysql, query, fpdf

Tenho uma consulta num sistema onde o usuário seleciona o mês e são mostrados os registros correspondentes na mesma página.  Eu quero imprimir o resultado da consulta mas como o form envia via GET:

```
<form action="" method="get" id='form-contato' class="form-horizontal col-md-10">
```

não consigo enviar para outra página e montar o pdf para imprimir. Existe uma maneira de enviar o resultado da query num Array e chamar o arquivo "imprimir.php"?

Lembrando que esta query muda a cada escolha de um novo mês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Existe um código JavaScript que imprime a página, não me recordo qual

Comment: Seria isso? [Como imprimir o conteúdo dentro de uma div HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/782/como-imprimir-o-conte%C3%BAdo-dentro-de-uma-div-html)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar **CSS** para determinar as áreas que você deseja imprimir, e criar um botão, que ao clicar ele chama a método **print**.

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
$("#print_page").on("click", function(){
  window.print();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Imprimir área desejada</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @media print {
      * {
        visibility:hidden;
      }
      .imprimir {
        visibility: visible;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;                                     
      }                                  
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <strong>Isto não vai ser impresso!</strong>  
  <div class="imprimir">
      Já isto e, apenas isto, será impresso!
      <input type="button" id="print_page" value="IMPRIMIR" />
  </div> 
  Aqui também não vai sair na impressão!            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando clico no botão não acontece nada... onde é que eu errei? Inseri o CSS , Declarei a função criei a DIV e o botão mas nada acontece.
Mesmo assim muito obrigado, já é um caminho a ser seguido.

Comment: Talvez tenha esquecido do **jQuery** adicione no seu html `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Eu declarei o jQuery sem sucesso.

Comment: Não entendi, o que você quis dizer!

Comment: Sem sucesso quer dizer que não funcionou. Eu presumo que como é um http, eu não precise mandar para o servidor o jquery, não?

Comment: Você pode fazer assim no botão, sem jquery: `<input type="button" value="IMPRIMIR" onclick="window.print();" />`

Comment: Valeu Wellingthon, vou tentar daqui a pouco, muito obrigado.

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado.

Comment: Se possível, aceita a resposta, pois assim a pergunta fica como resolvida, além de melhorar cada vez mais a qualidade do site.

Comment: Desculpe Wéllingthon, não sei como aceitar a resposta...