# Como imprimir somente uma parte do HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Pra imprimir uma página sei que devo utilizar

```
<button onclick="window.print()">
```

O que eu preciso saber é como printar uma DIV?

Ex:

```
<div id="divtoprint">
   //some code
</div>
```

Comment: pode especificar mais a sua pergunta!

Comment: Eu preciso imprimir todo o conteúdo que consta em uma determinada DIV no caso a div do segundo exemplo, não quero imprimir o conteúdo da página inteira como esta no primeiro exemplo

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, algumas com JavaScript, outras só com CSS. Um bom caminho é começar pelo mais simples, como esta solução só com CSS, [postada por Bennett McElwee no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618980/825789):

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Teria um exemplo em JS?

Comment: @ayowoleagbedejobi com JS https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/819/3635

Comment: Só uma duvida, utilizando somente o `#section-to-print` sem o `*` já não faz com que todos os elementos filhos apareçam?

Comment: Não, como tudo foi escondido com o `body *`, precisa desfazer isso em todos os descendentes da div. @LaércioLopes

Answer (score 1):

A função abaixo irá abrir um *popup* apenas com o conteúdo da `div` especificada para impressão, e irá aplicar também o CSS externo caso haja:

Botão para imprimir com o `id` da `div`:

```
<button onclick="printDIV('divtoprint')">Imprimir</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function printDIV(i){
   var cssEstilos = '';
   var imp = window.open('', 'div', 'width='+window.innerWidth+',height='+window.innerWidth);

   var cSs = document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']");
   for(x=0;x<cSs.length;x++){
      cssEstilos += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+cSs[x].href+'">';
   }

   imp.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
   imp.document.write(cssEstilos+'</head><body>');
   imp.document.write(document.getElementById(i).innerHTML);
   imp.document.write('</body></html>');

   setTimeout(function(){
      imp.print();
      imp.close();
   },500);
}
```

**Nota:** a tag `<link>` para carregar os seus CSS externos devem ter o atributo `rel='stylesheet'`. Ex.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Há diversas maneira de fazer isto, já que você quer em JavaScript, aqui tem um exemplo simples.

```
<body>
<div id="sua_div">Essa é a DIV</div>
<button id="btn">Clique para imprimir</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
   var conteudo = document.getElementById('sua_div').innerHTML,
   tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');

   tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
   tela_impressao.window.print();
   tela_impressao.window.close();
};
</script>
</body>
```

Espero ter ajudado. Aqui e só uma base, mas pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Essa pareceu ser bastante a resposta dada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/819/5878). Você só copiou e colou?

Comment: Sim amigo, Esqueci de referenciar. algum problema nao vou inventar a roda se ela já ta inventada.

Comment: No site, existe a opção de sinalizar como duplicata logo abaixo da pergunta. Se você conhece uma resposta que já responde bem ao que foi perguntado, você pode sinalizá-la. Isso evitará que conteúdos fiquem duplicados. Não é errado responder uma pergunta duplicata, desde que você gere algum conteúdo que ainda não esteja presente no site.