# Botão Direito Imprimir Html gera folha em branco - Asp.net MVC4

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Galera, estou com um problema no qual tenho uma página html. Ao clicar com botão direito -> Imprimir gera uma folha em branco no final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja reduzi o html da página a quase nada mas continua gerando essa folha extra. Reduzi o width e height mas também nao surtiu efeito. Acredito que possa ser algo no _Layout.cshtml ou coisa assim.

O que posso fazer para acabar com essa página extra?
Valeu

Comment: *"gera uma folha em branco no final"* será pq o html não cabe numa página? já tentou fazer testes removendo coisas ou mudando altura? o que verificou?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler  [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria você ignorar esse imprimir do navegador e criar um botão de impressão na tua página e com JS mandar imprimir um html otimizado para impressão.

Tem algumas dicas aqui de como fazer:
[Como imprimir o conteúdo dentro de uma div HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/782/como-imprimir-o-conte%C3%BAdo-dentro-de-uma-div-html)